# Not able to Set Multiple Reminders

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast

There is functionality in my app where a user can set multiple reminders. But the problem is that when user set time for reminder A and than for Reminder B, then reminder B only gets call. That is the intent for reminder A never gets call. In short Only one reminder is working all the time. Here is snippet of setting reminder and calling Broadcast.

```
public void setAlarm(int dayValue, int monthValue, int yearValue, int hourValue, int minValue, String message, int pos){

            int ID = 1;
        calendar.set(yearValue, monthValue, dayValue, hourValue, minValue, 0);
        Calendar tempCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,ReminderNissan.class);

        intent.putExtra("title",message);
        intent.putExtra("note",message);
        intent.putExtra("id", pos);

        Log.d("****Indide set alarm method*****", "PSOITION " + pos);

        if((tempCal.compareTo(calendar)==  -1) || (tempCal.compareTo(calendar)==  0)){
            try{
                db.open();
                db.setAlarm(id.get(pos).toString(), 1);
                db.close();
            }catch(SQLException exp){
                Log.d("SET ALARM OFF SQL EXCEPTION", exp.toString());
            }

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID,intent,0);

            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "*** ALARM SET AT ***  " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            try{
                db.open();
                db.setAlarm(id.get(pos).toString(), 0);
                db.close();
            }catch(SQLException exp){
                Log.d("SET ALARM OFF SQL EXCEPTION", exp.toString());
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Time Has Alredy Passed. Set proper Time. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure but it could be that you are overriding the alerts.

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID,intent,0);
```

the ID argument is always 1 in your case. Just make it an unique id and it should be fine fine.

Comment: So you mean I should increment ID whenever i call this method to set alarm i.e For alarm A ID=1 and for Alarm B Id=2. will it do.?

Answer (score 0):

Where did You call Your setAlarm-Method? I had an app, that works in a similar way, every time a alarm is active, I open an Activity with a cancel-Button. By pressing the button, it will set the setAlarm-Method again, so it will go forward to the next alarm. To do so, I had set a Flag to the pendingIntent

```
      PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```